# keyboard does not work in ubuntu installation

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am trying to setup a new VM using install ubuntu-22.04 desktop on vcenter server. When I am  on the final screen "Who are you?
I am unable to type anything. Tab on the keyboard works, but unbable to type.
Have tried wired keyboard and wireless. same issue.
Please advise.
Thanks

[image]